# Medalha de Guardião foi para dono da pergunta

Tags: bug, status-intencional, medalhas

Hoje pela manhã editei uma pergunta recebi os 2 pontos de reputação, mas a medalha de Guardião foi para dono da pergunta, o que devo fazer ?
[link para pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35534/ide-em-cloud-para-desenvolvimento-c-asp-net).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme a descrição, a medalha [Guardão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/82/custodian) é concedida quando o usuário...

> Completou pelo menos uma tarefa de análise. Esta medalha é concedida uma vez por tipo de análise

No caso, ela foi concedida ao Autor da Pergunta (AP) porque ele aprovou sua edição na fila de análise.

Existem outras medalhas para quem edita conteúdo, tais como [Editor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3/editor) e [Revisor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor).

Comment: Realmente você esta correto, o que fazemos com essa pergunta do BUG que não existe removo ?

Comment: @DiegoSantos Apenas marque a resposta como correta.